# lint-staged and tslint "warning" severity

Tags: typescript, tslint, lint-staged

In my project I use `tslint` with `"defaultSeverity": "warning"` option. 
Is there a way to configure `lint-staged` to catch warnings too and abort commit if they occurs?
My `lint-staged` configuration:

```
"lint-staged": {
    "core/src/main/resources/**/*.tsx": "node core/node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint",
    "gitDir": "../"
},
"scripts": {
  "test": "",
  "precommit": "lint-staged"
}
```